# Java Servlet always return a succes:false after getOutputStream().close()

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, outputstream

In Spring MVC I have the next controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/generacionGuias")
public @ResponseBody GeneracionGuiaEstafetaSolicitud procesarAlta(@ModelAttribute GeneracionGuiaEstafetaSolicitud instance,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    
    GeneracionGuiaEstafetaSolicitud respuesta = new GeneracionGuiaEstafetaSolicitud();
    respuesta.setSuccess(false);

    String fileZip = "generacionArchivosGuias";
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream zipFinalFile = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        respuesta = ((GeneracionGuiasEstafetaService) service).generacionDeDocumentosGuias(instance);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MicroServicioException("0002", e.toString());
    }
    try{
        zipFinalFile =((GeneracionGuiasEstafetaService) service).generadorZIP(respuesta);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Problema en la creación del archivo ZIP: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new  SibamexStoredProcedureException("000005","Problema con la generación del Archivo ZIP");
    }
    
    byte[] file = zipFinalFile.toByteArray();
    respuesta.setArchivo(file);
    
    try{
        response.resetBuffer();
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileZip + ".zip");
        response.getOutputStream().write(file);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        respuesta.setSuccess(true);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error en la generación del archivo zip: " + e.getMessage());
        respuesta.setSuccess(false);
    }finally {
        response.getOutputStream().close();
        respuesta.setSuccess(true);
    }

    logger.info("Regresa respuesta con archivo a descargar");

    return respuesta;
}
```

I create a ZIP file in the Service and convert it to a byte[], I try to write it in the response using the line response.getOutputStream().write(file); to try to download it from the front end, but when I get to response.getOutputStream().close(); it always returns a "Succes:false" even though the response returns a 200 code, any idea why it does this?

[Log printed in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvHoG.png)

Comment: Don't close that outpuststream. As a rule of thumb, if you don't create the stream don't close it. The stream is controlled by Tomcat (or whatever servlet container you use). You closing it here might eagerly close it leading to exceptions. Also this code doesn't really make sense, either write to the output stream or return an `@responseBody` doing both doesn't make sense.